# 16.04 Bad Magic Number - Load Kernel First

Tags: 16.04, error-handling

None of the existing posts found have actual solution for this...

I awoke this morning to a blank screen... couln't wake up the system... had to hit reset.

What resulted was error: invalid magic number and error: load kernel first...

Pressing continue sends me to the grub menu where none of the options allow me to boot into the system. They all get the same errors.

I literally did nothing to the system yesteday except use Chromium to check social media site. No updates were authorized... nothing changed.

My system drive is a Samsung EVO 840 SSD.

How can I fix this and get back in?

I booted into Live CD just to see if anything changed. but, I have no idea what to do once I get "in".

Comment: Try doing an fsck. Boot to GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, choose root access, type `fsck -f /` and report back.

Comment: @heynnema - Thanks for picking this one up. Unfortunately, a root access option does not appear in my advanced options menu.
I have options for three different kernels though (?) all on the same sdb1 disk. None of them will boot.

Comment: OK. I found what you were speaking of. I dropped to root and ran the command. It asked me if I wanted to FIX about 50 pages of problems... Nothing to lose, So I said yes to everything.
It looks like I have to reinstall clean again. I wish I knew what keeps causing this.

Comment: Sorry... I forgot the "select Recovery mode" in my instructions. Run fsck (`fsck -fy /`) a few more times, hopefully until it runs clean. Are you dual-booting Windows and Ubuntu? Do you mount Windows partitions in Ubuntu, or try to read Ubuntu partitions from Windows? Sounds like this has happened before?

Comment: Thank you for helping out. I got super frustrated and just nuked the SSD and started over... I'm working from a clean install now. reviewing everything I did with Samba and the printer installs to get those working again... I next need to figure out how to do a full image backup of the system so this doesn't catch me again.

Comment: Glad you got it going. Please do answer my questions regarding Windows, and any details on when/how this problem has occurred before.

Comment: Thanks again... To answer your question re:Windows, The system was/is strictly Ubuntu... No dual booting.
The problem simply appeared overnight... literally. I shut down the machine at night. And, the problem appeared on rebooting the next morning.
It reminds me of when a hard drive fails. But, this SSD checked out "golden".
I hope it doesn't happen again.